# Spring security configuration SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain permitAll problem

Tags: java, spring, security, model-view-controller, roles

If inside @Bean SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain build http chain with                 `.requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll();` controller with mapping "/auth" cannot be invoked due to 403 but if I use `requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()` I can proceed to that address. Why it is so?

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().disable().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            /*.requestMatchers("/myAccount").hasAuthority("VIEWACCOUNT")
            .requestMatchers("/myBalance").hasAnyAuthority("VIEWACCOUNT","VIEWBALANCE")
            .requestMatchers("/myLoans").hasAuthority("VIEWLOANS")
            .requestMatchers("/myCards").hasAuthority("VIEWCARDS")*/
            .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll();


    return http.build();
}
```

@RestController("/auth")
public class LoginController {

```
@Autowired
private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


@GetMapping
public String showUserString(@RequestBody User user) {
    return "Hello World!";
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement SecurityConfiguration like this:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        // .csrf().disable not recommended in prod environment
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
            .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );

        return http.build();
}
```

Then change this line

```java
@RestController("/auth")
```

to

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
```

and this line

```java
@GetMapping
```

to

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/showUserString", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```